# How to retrieve Bangla data in PHP from MS DOC file

Tags: php, unicode

I want to retrieve Bangla data that is written in MS word file using UNICODE. How can I retrieve this data using PHP? I can retrieve English data from DOC file using Antiword. But I cannot retrieve Bangla.

Comment: Do you have an example document you can put online, and maybe your php script that you are trying to use?

Comment: Can you work with the DOCX format? Extraction should be easier there.

Answer (score 0):

I have used PHP and COM (only on Windows Servers) to read document files.

Extracting text from Word Documents via PHP and COM

```
$word = new COM("word.application") or die ("Could not initialise MS Word object.");
$word->Documents->Open(realpath("Sample.doc")); 

# Extract content.
$content = (string) $word->ActiveDocument->Content; 

echo $content; 

$word->ActiveDocument->Close(false); 

$word->Quit();

$word = null; 

unset($word);
```

I think you will have to use Windows Servers to get this done correctly. Or can you convert the document into OpenOffice format and give it a go? More details on PHP COM are available here. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php

Answer (score -1):

You may solve this by using **fopen()** function.

Comment: MS Word is a proprietary format, simply opening it and reading the contents won't work.